# Fedena Error in Boot.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedena

> /home/palpandi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@fedena_zip/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning:
>   Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed
>   on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
>
> /home/palpandi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@fedena_zip/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in
>   `const_missing': uninitialized constant Rails::Boot::Bundler
>   (NameError)

Using Rails 2.3.5
      Ruby 1.8.7
      ubuntu 12.04

Comment: sooo, is bundler installed on your schmubutu machine?

Comment: use this guide http://aboobacker.in/installing-project-fedena-in-14-04/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The correct way to solve this is to go to your project folder, then in `config/boot.rb` go to the very bottom, and just before the `Rails.boot!` line add the following :

```
begin
 require "rubygems"
 require "bundler"
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound
   raise RuntimeError, "Bundler couldn't find some gems." + "Did you run bundle install?"
end

class Rails::Boot
  def run
    load_initializer

    Rails::Initializer.class_eval do
      def load_gems
        @bundler_loaded ||= Bundler.require :default, Rails.env
      end
    end

    Rails::Initializer.run(:set_load_path)
  end
end
```

This will solve the "uninitialized constant Authorization" error.

Answer (score 0):

put this line in your boot.rb

```
begin
 require "rubygems"
 require "bundler"
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound 
   raise RuntimeError, "Bundler couldn't find some gems." + "Did you run bundle install?"
end
```

or

`gem install bundler`

and after adding:

`gem 'bundler'`

in line 2 in config/boot.rb (just after require 'rubygems')